# Como fazer essa condição funcionar?

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso de uma ajuda. 
O que estou tentando fazer é parecido com as ofertas do peixe urbano, ativas enquanto o contador de tempo funciona e após o termino as informações são substituídas. porém quando uso else não funciona pois a primeira condição continua sendo verdadeira e se uso mais um if ele adiciona as informações de promoção encerrada junto com as da promoção ativa. Como consigo criar essa condição corretamente? Obs: Sou iniciante rs
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
  <?php 
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM estabelecimentos ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4");
        $sql->execute();
        $portal = $sql->fetchAll();
  ?>


    <?php
            $currentDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            foreach($portal as $key => $value) {
                ?>

                <div class="col s12 m3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode( $value['imagem'] ).'"/>';  ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">

                            <span class="card-title"><?php echo $value['nome']; ?></span>
                            <h5><?php echo $value['produto']; ?></h5>

                            <?php if($value['status'] == 'promo'){ ?>

                                        <div class="ticket"> 
                                           <span><img src="img/flame.png" alt=""></span>
                                         <span>Promoção turbinada</span>
                        </div>
                                           <p><span class="promo"><?php echo 'A partir de '.'R$'.$value['promo']. ',00'; ?></span></p>
                                        <div class="countdown" data-date="<?php echo $value['fimpromo']; ?>" data-time="<?php echo $value['datetime']; ?>"></div>

                            <?php } if ($value['fimpromo']<= $currentDateTime) {  ?>

                          <div class="ticket ticket-closed">
                             <span><img src="img/cancel.png" alt=""></span>
                             <span>Promoção Encerrada</span>
                          </div>

                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
                   <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente desta forma:

```
<section>
<div class="destaques">
     <div class="container">
        <h2 class="title center-align">Os Melhores Restaurantes!</h2>
        <p class="center-align">Do Rodízio ao à la carte, garanta já o seu:</p>
        <div class="row">       
            <?php $currentDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');  ?>

                <?php foreach($portal as $key => $value) :  ?>
            <div class="col s12 m3">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image">
                  <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode( $value['imagem'] ).'"/>';  ?>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                  <span class="card-title"><?php echo $value['nome']; ?></span>
                  <h5><?php echo $value['produto']; ?></h5>
                  <?php if($value['status'] == 'promo'): ?>
                    <?php if ($value['fimpromo'] <= $currentDateTime) : ?>
                      <?php 
                        $sql2 = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE estabelecimentos SET status = :status WHERE id = :id");
                        $sql2->execute([':status' => 'closed', ':id' => $value['id']]);
                      ?>
                      <div class="ticket ticket-closed">
                        <span><img src="img/cancel.png" alt=""></span>
                        <span>Promoção Encerrada</span>
                      </div>
                    <?php else: ?>
                      <div class="ticket"> 
                        <span><img src="img/flame.png" alt=""></span>
                        <span>Promoção turbinada</span>
                      </div>                          
                      <div class="countdown" data-date="<?php echo $value['fimpromo']; ?>" data-time="<?php echo $value['datetime']; ?>"></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <p><span class="promo"><?php echo 'A partir de '.'R$'.$value['preco']. ',00'; ?></span></p>                        
                  <?php endif; ?>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!! Funcionou!